# Using Green's Theorem to find the flux

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, greens-theorem

$F(x,y)=\langle y^2+e^x,x^2+e^y\rangle$. Using green's theorem in its circulation and flux forms, determine the flux and circulation of $F$ around the triangle $T$, where $T$ is the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(1,0),$ and $(0,1)$, oriented counterclockwise.

**My Try:**

$f=y^2+e^x$

$g=x^2+e^y$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=2x$$
$$\int F\cdot dr=\int\int_R(2x-2y)dA$$
$$\int^{1}_{0}\int_{0}^{1-x}(2x-2y)dydx=0$$
**My quesiton: Is my above attempt correct? Because I got the answer as $0$**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is correct indeed we have that the region is symmetric with respect to $y=x$ and the integral for $2x$ is equal to the integral for $2y$ that is

$$\int\int_R 2x\,dA=\int\int_R2y\,dA \implies \int\int_R(2x-2y)dA=0$$

Comment: How did you get $\int_0^x$? Can you please elaborate the answer.

Comment: @user982787 Sorry I had assumed the third vertex in $(1,1)$. Your result seems correct.